# Django: Calling views.py with argument

Tags: django, url, view

Hi Stackoverflow people,

I am using the Userena package for my user registration site. The package allows to change the template or the form class during with the call of the views.py function "def profile_edit" (if I understood it correctly).

The full header of the view function is:

```
def profile_edit(request, username, edit_profile_form=EditUserProfileForm,
             template_name='userena/profile_form.html', success_url=None,
             extra_context=None):
```

The demo project calls the view function in the template through the urls.py with the statement

```
{% url userena_profile_edit user.username %}
```

When I try to change the form parameter for example with

```
{% url userena_profile_edit user.username edit_profile_form=EditUserProfileForm %}
```

I get the follow error, which does not make sense to me:

```
Caught ValueError while rendering: Don't mix *args and **kwargs in call to reverse()!
```

I have also tried to the specify the kwargs dict, but it did not work either.

```
{% url userena_profile_edit user.username kwargs={'edit_profile_form':EditUserProfileForm} %}
```

How can I correctly call the function? I am confused why the last statement would not work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should show us how the relevant line in `urls.py` looks like.

Comment: # Edit profile
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\.\w]+)/edit/$',
       userena_views.profile_edit,
       name='userena_profile_edit'),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about making the username a kwarg?

```
{% url userena_profile_edit username=user.username edit_profile_form=EditUserProfileForm %}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because your mixing args and kwargs. You can't do that in a [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) call. `user.username` is an arg, try using it as a kwarg:

```
{% url userena_profile_edit username=user.username edit_profile_form=EditUserProfileForm %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

When I try to call the function like you have suggested, I get the error:

Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'userena_profile_edit' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'username': u'Mark', 'edit_profile_form': ''}' not found. Is there maybe a different method I have to use?

Comment: Well you already have `EditUserProfile` as a default in your `profile_edit` function. Have your tried just `{% url userena_profile_edit user.username %}`?

Comment: Well, actually wanted to introduce a bit more flexibility by changing the forms. Therefore, I wanted to add the new argument.

Comment: Solution: I left {% url userena_profile_edit user.username %} and changed the urls.py: url(r'^(?P<username>[\.\w]+)/edit/m/$',
       userena_views.profile_edit,
       name='userena_profile_edit_m',
       kwargs={'edit_profile_form':EditMProfileForm})